# WebBindingInitializer won't execute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How can I make `initBinder()` method to start every time form loads and submits. This example has responsibility to convert date from String to `java.util.Date`.

In my servlet-context.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
        <bean class="org.example.web.ExampleBindingInitializer" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Here is my implementation of WebBindingInitializer:

```
public class ExampleBindingInitializer implements WebBindingInitializer {

    private ExampleService exampleService;

    @Autowired
    public ExampleBindingInitializer(ReservationService reservationService) {
        this.reservationService = reservationService;
    }

    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, WebRequest request) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
    }
}
```

I didn't made any modifications in controller where ExampleService methods are called. Where I'm wrong?

When I put `initBinder()` method with `@InitBinder` annotation to my controller, everything works fine. That doesn't satisfy me beacause I want to have that in external class.

Comment: Can you post the controller method that accepts the object containing the date?

Comment: Acually if it works or not depends on which version of Spring you are using. Please add the version. If you are using a newer spring version you should use the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` instead of the `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` included in your configuration and your bean declared prior to it.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
        <bean class="org.example.web.ExampleBindingInitializer" />
    </property>
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

When Spring scans for handlers the first registered handler that fits is used.  `mvc:annotation-driven` registers a few handlers which may be being used in place of your handler.

Comment: No success. At the beginning of configuration I put exactly this. After that I have mvc:resources tag for static resources, tiles configuration, component-scan on my packages, SimpleMappingExceptionResolver for specific exceptions and ResourceBundleMessageSource at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You must remove or comment out `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` from your dispatcher-servlet. [Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

Answer (score 0):

The class, `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`, you use is old and deprecated. You shouldn't use it.

I assume you have `<mvc:annotation-driven />` or `@EnableWebMvc` which registers the recommended and supported `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`. You could create a `BeanPostProcessor` to set the desired property on the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`.

However what you actually should do is create a custom converter and register that using the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` namespace. That is the recommended way of doing things and not using a `WebBindingInitializer` anymore.